# Minimum number of transistors to implement CMOS logic of this function

Tags: cmos, boolean-algebra

I have designed the following circuit to implement CMOS logic of:

\$\text{out}=\overline{(a+b).\overline{c}+e.(\overline{f}+\overline{g})}\$

I’m looking for the optimal circuit with the minimum number of transistors, is there any better implementation?

[image]

Comment: You're allowed to just make c' without counting the transistors to make it?

Comment: @ThePhoton yes it is possible.

Comment: It's not a question of possible, it's a question of the specfications of the problem.

Comment: @ThePhoton No, I mean that if we consider we have a,b,c,e,f,g and a’,b’,c’,e’,g’,f’ then design the above function

Comment: Yes, but does your problem specify that you get all 12 of those signals as inputs, or do you only get a, b, c, d, e, f, g?

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, we are allowed to use all 12 signal whenever needed.

Comment: Then this is the (or a) minimal implementation. You have 6 inputs, and you use 6 transistors above and 6 transistors below the output. If you removed any transistor, you'd also have to remove an input. In which case you wouldn't be implementing the same logic.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum number of transistors = 2x the number of variables + 1x the number of inverted inputs.

You have 12 transistors with 6 variables.

> is there any better implementation?

Better in what way?

Usually ideal Logic depends on what assumptions you make and **more importantly specify.**

Comment: If the minimum required is what you said, how do you implement this function with 15 transistors?